# Microservices - one domain and multiple functions that scale in different speeds

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

I am new in DDD and microservices and I'd like some direction on how to approach a situation.

Let's say that I have a system with Orders. Each order can have multiple items. So I am thinking that this will be a specific domain.

Then as I look at orders more I find that we will offer the following:

- each item in the order is gathered from the different warehouses and the status of each item (e.g. prepared, moving to gathering point) along with etas is displayed to customers for their order.
- after all items are gathered we provide status, eta and gps location of the order with regular updates.

So orders has the API to place an order and get order details. But also subscribes to all these other systems that send updates for item gathering and order delivery location and progress.

What felt as the Order domain now seems to have components/functions that get scaled at a different cadence. E.g. i only need 10 order api instances, but 50 order notification handler instances, also we take orders 24/7 but we gather items  and deliver orders only on certain days and hours. These two share a lot of the data ( the orders and the items in the order) and need to be reported together all the time.

So my initial thought was to have the order  rest api and the notification handlers be different deployable units, but share the same order database tables.

Searching around this looks to be referred as an antipattern, but the examples cite different domains, when in this case it seems to be the same domain.

How would you handle this when using DDD and microservices? Is there a known problem/pattern that i could read more about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting stuck on focusing on the data instead of your context.
The point of your data repository is to serialize your context and nothing more. So, it doesn't matter if there's data duplication across contexts as long as the duplication is not because the context was poorly defined.

For example, Your Order context might contain an Order Description and in your Delivery Context you might need that description for a Postal Label. You'll save the same description in 2 places and that's okay. You might decide in the future to add a "delivery Id" to the Postal Label and since you have separate contexts, this addition will be trivial and not affect your Order Context in any way.

I didn't understand what you meant by "10 order api instances or 50 notification handlers". So I cannot address that.

> So orders has the API to place an order and get order details. But also subscribes to all these other systems that send updates for item gathering and order delivery location and progress.

Order context doesn't need to deal with Gathering Items, Delivery or locations. Or their events. You need a `Delivery Context` and possibly a `Gathering Context` too.

In summary, It's fine to save the same data in different contexts as long as it makes sense in the Ubiquitous Language. Also, design your contexts against the major functionalities in your system (order, gathering and delivering).